# Kotlin for Technical Analysis Indicators

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, design-patterns

I want to use **Kotlin for technical analysis framework**, because I have several additional libraries in the java code.
I will plan to extend engine for calculation of indicators and strategies.

For example there is present usage of simple moving averages in the condition inside of some strategy:

`if (EMA(C, 24) > MA(L, 100)) { ... }`

So, there are present two indicators (functions) for exponential moving average EMA, and standard moving average MA. Which have to be calculated from Close prices, and Low prices (it is some standard series of double values), the lengths are 24 and 100.

This condition which directly included indicators are very good for final user of framework and I want to kept this style!

Now the problem: For example, this condition with indicators is part of some strategy code. But this part of code is calculated per price bar. It means many times for each price value. 
The indicators have own history and can use some additional context, for additional configuration or data. 
Ideal state will be, EMA(C, 24) function expression has to be bind with specific object/instance of indicator which is not singleton but belongs to this expression, because have some history, added context etc. But I do not want to create objects externally! The structure of condition example has to be kept. 
Or use some function in function with possibility to inject context or additional data, and kept some history. 
Main problem is that this line is perform for each bar, it is not just one calling, it is incremental calling of this condition.

Kotlin has many possibilities for functions, lambdas, objects. I'm trying to find some best solution for this type of usecase, which will be FAST/GOOD performance in one hand, and with good writing of conditions in other hand.

Thanks for help and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to create separate classes, you can try using lambdes passing the values from the main class:

```
typealias averageAlg = (a: String, b: Int, history: MutableList<Int>) -> Int
class AverageClass(var emaAlg: averageAlg, var maAlg: averageAlg) {

    private val historyEma = ArrayList<Int>() // for store configuration
    private val historyMa = ArrayList<Int>()

    fun calculation() {
        if (EMA("C", 20) < MA("L", 100)) {} else {}
    }
    // the names of your functions will remain unchanged.
    private fun EMA(a: String, b: Int): Int = emaAlg(a, b, historyEma)
    private fun MA(a: String, b: Int): Int = maAlg(a, b, historyMa)
}
```

Define algorithms that can change. For exampe:

```
val emaAlg: averageAlg = { a, b, historyEma ->
    val calcValue = a.length + b
    historyEma.add(calcValue) // modify history
    println(historyEma)
    calcValue // return current value
}
...
val averageClass = AverageClass(emaAlg, maAlg)
averageClass.calculation()
```

Variant 2. Or you can create separate classes:

```
class EMA(private var emaF: averageAlg) {
    val list = ArrayList<Int>() // for store configuration
    fun f(a: String, b: Int): Int = emaF(a, b, list)
}

class MA(private var maF: averageAlg) {
    val list = ArrayList<Int>() // for store configuration
    fun f(a: String, b: Int): Int = maF(a, b, list)
}

val ema = EMA { a, b, history ->
    // here your algorithm
}

val ma = MA { a, b, history ->
    // here your algorithm
}
if (ema.f("C", 24) < ma.f("L", 100)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. This design pattern is very important for me, because it will be important/main part of framework. So, I need "best" solution. I like your proposals. But   I have for example two or ten EMA in one `calculation()` method. For example conditions are: `if (EMA(C, 20) > EMA(C, 32) || EMA(C, 200) < L[1]`  It means that the function EMA is more times in the code. Each EMA needs separated history and context. I don't want to ema1, ema2, ema3 instances, it is too complicated for final framework user.

Comment: @Antonin Fischer I was still thinking about your task. Have you looked at the use of the "State" pattern? The "State" pattern controls the change in the behavior of an object when its internal state changes. In this case, the ema1, ema2, ema3 instances will be states and will not be visible to the final framework user. And between them it will be easy to switch.

Comment: Yes, State pattern can be used: first EMA(C, 32) is calculated. Internal state will be switched after calculation, EMA(C, 200) creates internal new state instance and switch after calculation. After whole cycle, the internal state will be reset to process first state again. Instances are hidden. There is problem of flow and processing order of EMAs, there is no binding or unique key. If the condition has "else" part there can be some next EMA, which can be taken sooner and mix/crash internal state memory, because it was not present in previous bar cycle. I don't see effective solution here.

Comment: I start prefer your second solution with real instances. Where is use for update "f()" method. These instances can have many next possibilities for access series, usage of operator overloading (fast access to series history), and pre-configuration in initial section. Yes, it is not my first requirement. Each instance need specific variable and has to be created in initial section. I have to find some good approach for this type of initialization and good pattern for naming of instances (unification principles). Thanks for help!